# Terraform import returns Invalid ARN while importing ELB of type classic

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elb

I am trying to import an classic load balancer which has been created manually.

The command that I am using

```
terraform import aws_lb.[lb_name] arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:[region]:[account_id]:loadbalancer/[lb_name]
```

the error that i am getting

```
 aws_lb.[lb_name]: Importing from ID "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:[account_id]:loadbalancer/[lb_name]"...
aws_lb.[lb_name]: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_lb for import
aws_lb.[lb_name]: Refreshing state... [id=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:[account_id]:loadbalancer/[lb_name]
╷
│ Error: retrieving ALB (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:[account_id]:loadbalancer/[lb_name]): ValidationError: 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:[account_id]:loadbalancer/[lb_name]' is not a valid load balancer ARN
│       status code: 400, request id: bb8dc4b4-4c02-4883-950b-9e4b5e6fc947
│
│
╵
```

What could be causing this?
And, Is it possible to retrieve the ARN of an ELB?

Comment: You need only the name of the ELB if you are really using the ELB Classic: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elb#import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using **Classic Load Balancer** which is the previous generation, it basically does not have **ARN**. I am using the `name` instead, below mine name is `binh-test-clb`.

Here is my **Terraform resource**:

```
resource "aws_elb" "clb" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

Here is my **import** command:

```bash
terraform import aws_elb.clb binh-test-clb
```

References:

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elb

Comment: thank you so much for the solution. 

Also one more thing that i messed up was resource "aws_lb" in place of "aws_elb"